# Intercept object created not from ninject kernel

Tags: ninject-2, ninject-extensions

Let say I have a class :

```
public class SomeClass {
    public virtual void InterceptedMethod ()
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

I'm using `Ninject` with *interception* extension. I want to intercept `InterceptedMethod`. If I created object from ninject kernel, that method is intercepted.

```
kernel = InitializeKernel ();
SomeClass objectFromKernel = kernel.Get<SomeClass> ();
objectFromKernel.InterceptedMethod (); // this method is intercepted.
```

But, if I created object not from kernel, that method is NOT intercepted.

```
kernel = InitializeKernel ();
SomeClass objectSelfCreated = new SomeClass ();
objectSelfCreated.InterceptedMethod (); // this method is NOT intercepted.
```

Is it possible to intercept self-created object using ninject ? If possible, how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Ninject can not help you in this situation. You have to create a proxy yourself or change the design so that the object is created by Ninject. See the documentation of your proxy factory about how to do this.